# strcmp crashes when comparing with a malloc array

Tags: c, strcmp

The strcmp cause the program to crash, Why is that? 
When removing strcmp it works well, and also with strcpy makes it crash

```
size_t maxLineLen=1024;
char *line = (char*)malloc(maxLineLen);
while(getline(&line, &maxLineLen,stdin)!= -1){
int h =strlen(line);
for (int i = 0; i < h; i++){
             if(strcmp(line[0], "a") == 0)  {
        printf("a found  %c \n ",line[i]);
            break;
        }

    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: They say [you shouldn't case the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: `line[0]` is a `char`, not a `char *`. You probably wanted to write `if (line[0] == 'a')` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strcmp` function expects a `char *` for the first argument, but you're passing a `char`.  Similarly with `strcpy`.  This caused undefined behavior.

Your compiler should have given you a warning regarding this.

If what you're trying to do is see if a given character in the string is `a`, you would do it like this:

```
if (line[i] == 'a')
```

Comment: So can yoou explain to me why this also willnot work
 if(strcmp(*(line+i), "a") == 0){

Comment: @MFB The expression `*(line+i)` is the same as `line[i]`, which is of type `char`, and therefore invalid as the first argument to `strcmp`.

Answer (score 2):

In your code `line` is pointer to character(s). `strcmp` takes pointers to characters to compare but here

```
if(strcmp(line[0], "a") == 0)
//        ^^^^^^^^
```

you are passing character instead of a pointer to it.

Solution:

```
if(strcmp(line, "a") == 0)
// ...
```

or

```
if(line[0] == 'a')
// ...
```

Side note: [there is no need to cast returned value of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1141471). You should however check it for errors:

```
char *line;
line = malloc(maxLineLen);
if (line == NULL)
    perror("oh dear! Go on holidays.\n");
```

Comment: if(strcmp(line[0], 'a') == 0) doesnot work also but if (line[i] == 'a') works

Comment: @MFB if(strcmp(line[0], 'a') == 0) doesn't work for sure

Comment: can you explain to me why this also willnot work if(strcmp(*(line+i), "a") == 0){

Comment: @MFB strcmp takes pointer to char, but *(line+i) is character itself, not a pointer to char, however if *(line+i) == 'a' is true then strcmp((line+i), "a") == 0 will work in your case as well. But you should use first comparison to compare single characters and strcmp to compare multicharacter strings.

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp(line[0], ...` is wrong. Use `strcmp(line, ...)`.

You should `#include <string.h>`, so your compiler will show an error. Otherwise always compile with all warnings enabled and read the warnings your compiler shows you.

Comment: I want to compare it character by character

Comment: @MFB [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) does exactly that. Where is the problem ? Read about C strings and string functions.

Comment: Thanks I will test it